# How to make an awesome star rating

Tags: jquery-mobile, rating

Is there a simple way to generate a 5 star rating element in Jquery-mobile?
Similar to http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use any jQuery plugin that fulfills this task. In the past, I have used the jQuery Star Rating plugin at

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

The only thing you need to think about is to stop jQuery Mobile from rendering the radio buttons with its own style. You can achieve this by adding `data-role="none"` to the input tag, see

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

Comment: Yeah... this doesnt work. in what order do you put your jscript in terms of declaration?

Answer (score 11):

I find the [jQuery Raty plugin](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty) a lot easier to use!

I could never get the class="star" to work with fyneworks.

Comment: I must say that I agree; I tried both and can get star-rating working in a standalone jQuery page, but could not get things to display correctly when integrated into a jQuery Mobile responsive setup. While Raty works fine in that setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a mobile rating component, take a look at the http://demo.mobiscroll.com/rating

EDIT: And the scroller integrates with jQuery Mobile Themes.
Tutorial for building a rating system with jQM + Rating & Grading scroller [here](http://blog.mobiscroll.com/building-a-movie-rating-system-with-jquery-mobile-and-mobiscroll/).

Comment: Mobiscroll isn't free. It's $8.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to use http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ together with jquery-mobile (version 1.4.5)

the above mentioned trick with data-role="none" on the input field does not work.
you need to render an own  tag around. I used the most simple example on page http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing

```
<div data-role="none">
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="3"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="4"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="5"/>
</div>
```

adjustments to color and size is quite difficult and needs changes to the star.gif and .css file

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with Jquery Mobile.
Hope you like it:

```
<style>
    .rated { background-color: yellow !important; }
    .rating a { border: 0px !important; }
</style>

<div class="rating" id="first">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="star" data-vote="1" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="star" data-vote="2" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="star" data-vote="3" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="star" data-vote="4" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="star" data-vote="5" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>

$(".rating a").on("vmouseover", function () {

    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    $("#" + id + ".rating a").each(function (i, v) {
    $(v).removeClass("rated");
  });

  $(this).prevAll().each(function (i, v) {
    $(v).addClass("rated");
  });
  $(this).addClass("rated");

  $("#" + id).data("vote", $(this).data("vote"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lgrillo/cz7z479j/